# md-toolbar background-color: transparent not working

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I've been banging my head on this one for a while....i have no idea why the background of my md-toolbar remains white even though i change the CSS.

I have a sample of my project here:

http://abc.morado.xyz:32782/#/index

my default HTML page that renders all the views looks like this:

```
<div layout="row" class="full-height transparent">
<!-- left sidebar -->

<!--<md-sidenav class="admin-sidebar-left md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="layout.sideMenuSize !== 'hidden' && $mdMedia('gt-sm')" ui-view="sidebarLeft" ng-class="{ 'admin-sidebar-collapsed': layout.sideMenuSize == 'icon' }" ng-mouseover="layoutController.activateHover()" ng-mouseleave="layoutController.removeHover()"></md-sidenav>-->

<!-- main content -->
<div id="admin-panel" layout="column" flex class="transparent">
    <!-- loading animation -->
    <tri-loader></tri-loader>

    <!-- top toolbar -->
    <md-toolbar class=" transparent" ng-if="layout.showToolbar" md-theme="{{triSkin.elements.toolbar}}" ui-view="toolbar" ng-class="[layout.toolbarSize,layout.toolbarClass]"></md-toolbar>

    <!-- scrollable content -->
    <md-content ng-class="layout.contentClass" flex tri-default-content ui-view="content"></md-content>

    <div ui-view="belowContent"></div>
</div>

<!-- right sidebar -->
<md-sidenav layout layout-fill class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="notifications" ui-view="sidebarRight"></md-sidenav>
```

And the header gets rendered in my config file:

```
.state('triangular.header', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                toolbar: {
                    templateProvider: function($templateCache, $http, triLayout) {
                        return $http.get(triLayout.layout.toolbarTemplateUrl, {cache: $templateCache })
                            .then(function(response) {
                                return response.data;
                            });
                    },
                    controllerProvider: function(triLayout) {
                        return triLayout.layout.toolbarController;
                    },
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                },
                content: {
                    templateProvider: function($templateCache, $http, triLayout) {
                        return $http.get(triLayout.layout.contentTemplateUrl, {cache: $templateCache })
                            .then(function(response) {
                                return response.data;
                            });
                    }
                },
                belowContent: {
                    template: '<div ui-view="belowContent"></div>'
                }
            }
        })
```

I've seen these solutions online but they dont work in my case...

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4379

[My own styles in angular material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100952/my-own-styles-in-angular-material-ui)

If you go to my link above and try playing with the CSS yourself, you'll find that setting the background on either the md-toolbar tag or the div inside said tag, only makes the background an opaque white.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have no idea when the background of my md-toolbar remains white even though i change the CSS

The background of that element *is* transparent, as you have specified in your CSS.

The white you see is simply the background of the body element.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you see that the `#admin-panel` `background-color` is  white?

Comment: Sorry, you’re right, it isn’t that one – it is simply the body background. But I am not sure how you were expecting any different result here to begin with – that when an element has transparent background, whatever lies below it will “shine through”, is only natural.

Comment: So, in that case is there anyway to make a sticky header toolbar and not have any background? kind of like in this example? https://projects.invisionapp.com/share/HU6O2XEY7/#/screens/146030680

Comment: My point rather is, if the background is transparent, why isnt the rest of the content (i.e. pictures et all) not shining through?

Comment: Well that’s because you only made the content inside of the `md-content` element scrollable, but not the whole page as a whole.